# How to show that if $a,b > 0$ and $0 < \lambda <1$ then $a^\lambda b^{1-\lambda} \leq \lambda a+(1-\lambda )b$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that if $a,b > 0$ and $0 < \lambda <1$ then $a^\lambda b^{1-\lambda} \leq \lambda a+(1-\lambda )b$. Here is the proof from the article that I'm reading:[image]

But I don't understand it well. I don't see how Derivative helped here.

Any other solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi'(t) < 0$ for $0 < t < 1$, therefore $\phi$ is (strictly) monotonically *decreasing*
on $(0, 1]$.

$\phi'(t) > 0$ for $t > 1$, therefore $\phi$ is (strictly) monotonically *increasing*
on $[1, \infty)$.

It follows that $\phi$ has an absolute minimum at $t = 1$: $\phi(t) \ge \phi(1) = 0$
for all $t > 0$, which is what (s)he wanted to prove.

Because of the strict monotonicity,
equality holds only for $t = 1$, which corresponds to $a = b$ in the original
inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: take $log$ and show its concave.