# Proving $a^{\lambda}b^{1-\lambda}<\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$ for $0<\lambda<1$ and $b>a$.

Tags: inequality

I want to show that $a^{\lambda}b^{1-\lambda}<\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$ for $0<\lambda<1$ and $b>a>0$. I'm aware a similar question has been asked here: [How to show that if $a,b > 0$ and $0 < \lambda <1$ then $a^\lambda b^{1-\lambda} \leq \lambda a+(1-\lambda )b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161365/how-to-show-that-if-a-b-0-and-0-lambda-1-then-a-lambda-b1-lambda) however I want to use some parts given beforehand in my response.

So before attempting this part, I was asked to deduce that $\frac{y-x}{y}<\log y-\log x<\frac{y-x}{x}$ for $y>x>0$ using mean value theorem.

Next, deduce that for $b>c>a>0$, $\log a<\log c +\frac{a-c}{c}$ and $\log b<\log c +\frac{b-c}{c}$

Afterwards, show that $a<\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b<b$ for $0<\lambda<1$.

After having shown these three results, I attempted the inequality with the substitution $c=\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$ since this value fulfills the conditions set on $c$.

This gives me $\log a<\log \big(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b\big) +\frac{a-\lambda a-(1-\lambda)b}{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b}$ and $\log b<\log\big(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b\big) +\frac{b-\lambda a-(1-\lambda)b}{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b}$. However from this point I'm completely stuck, adding the inequalities doesn't help, I tried to form another one using the fact that $\log c<\log a +\frac{c-a}{a}$ and adding it to the first inequality to cancel the logs but that didn't help since I can't simplify $\frac{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b-a}{a}+\frac{a-\lambda a-(1-\lambda)b}{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b}>0$.

Could someone help me use the previous parts to help construct an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\log a<\log c +\frac{a-c}{c}$ and $\log b<\log c +\frac{b-c}{c}$. Multiply the first inequality by $\lambda$, the second one by $1-\lambda$ and add. You get $\lambda \log a +(1-\lambda) \log b \leq [\lambda +(1-\lambda) ] \log c +(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b)/c- (\lambda +(1-\lambda))=\log c$ . No just take exponential.